# Redirect traffic from Facebook to specific page using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all traffic coming from facebook to a specific page. In my .htacess file I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?facebook\.com
RewriteRule ^$ /wouldyouratherquestions.php [L]
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I'm new to .htacess, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your site running on https?

Answer (score 0):

Your RewritePattern `^$` matches the homepage only, if you want to redirect all requests ,change  `^$` to  `^(.*)$` in the pattern :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?facebook\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wouldyouratherquestions.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wouldyouratherquestions.php [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wouldyouratherquestions.php` is a condition to the rule  it avoids rewriting the destination to itself.

Comment: Good mod_rewrite advice, but I strongly suspect this won't work either, because Facebook is running https these days and won't give you the referrer unless you're https as well